# Difference between the weblogic9.2 and 10.3 ? Is it possible to run the 9.2 working on 10.3?

Tags: java, jsp, weblogic

I am having project running on weblogic10.3 , but i want to run on weblogic 9.2.what are the changes need to make on the jsp tags ?

what is the difference between the weblogic 10.3 and 9.2 ?

```
<Jan 31, 2011 5:24:36 PM EST> <Warning> <netuix> <BEA-423420> <Redirect is executed in                  begin or refresh action. Redirect url is /console/console.portal?      _nfpb=true&_pageLabel=HomePage1.> 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mirror/declaration/ClassDeclaration 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) 
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source) 
    at javelin.mirror.Utilities.createMirrorType(Utilities.java:68) 
    at javelin.mirror.Utilities.createReferenceType(Utilities.java:85) 
    at javelin.ProxySourceFile$ProxyEnv.getTypeDeclaration(ProxySourceFile.java:806) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspLibrary.getClassInfo(JspLibrary.java:1259) 
    at javelin.jsp.tag.TagInfoEx.getSetterTypes(TagInfoEx.java:491) 
    at javelin.jsp.tag.TagInfoEx.initAttributeTypes(TagInfoEx.java:397) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspActionChecker.checkActionStart(JspActionChecker.java:287) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspActionChecker.checkActions(JspActionChecker.java:217) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspActionChecker.checkActions(JspActionChecker.java:231) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspActionChecker.check(JspActionChecker.java:157) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspCheckContext.check(JspCheckContext.java:78) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspAnalyzer.check(JspAnalyzer.java:59) 
    at javelin.ProxySourceFile._check(ProxySourceFile.java:152) 
    at javelin.SourceFile.masterCheck(SourceFile.java:777) 
    at javelin.SourceFile.check(SourceFile.java:297) 
    at javelin.SourceFile.check(SourceFile.java:318) 
    at javelin.ProxySourceFile.codeGen(ProxySourceFile.java:222) 
    at javelin.SourceFile.codeGen(SourceFile.java:310) 
    at javelin.client.ClientUtilsImpl$CodeGenJob.run(ClientUtilsImpl.java:1105) 
    at javelin.client.Job.performJob(Job.java:81) 
    at javelin.client.ThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPool.java:215) 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mirror/declaration/ClassDeclaration 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) 
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source) 
    at javelin.mirror.Utilities.createMirrorType(Utilities.java:68) 
    at javelin.mirror.Utilities.createReferenceType(Utilities.java:85) 
    at javelin.ProxySourceFile$ProxyEnv.getTypeDeclaration(ProxySourceFile.java:806) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspLibrary.getClassInfo(JspLibrary.java:1259) 
    at javelin.jsp.tag.TagInfoEx.getSetterTypes(TagInfoEx.java:491) 
    at javelin.jsp.tag.TagInfoEx.initAttributeTypes(TagInfoEx.java:397) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspActionChecker.checkActionStart(JspActionChecker.java:287) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspActionChecker.checkActions(JspActionChecker.java:217) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspActionChecker.checkActions(JspActionChecker.java:231) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspActionChecker.check(JspActionChecker.java:157) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspCheckContext.check(JspCheckContext.java:78) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspAnalyzer.check(JspAnalyzer.java:59) 
    at javelin.ProxySourceFile._check(ProxySourceFile.java:152) 
    at javelin.SourceFile.masterCheck(SourceFile.java:777) 
    at javelin.SourceFile.check(SourceFile.java:297) 
    at javelin.SourceFile.check(SourceFile.java:318) 
    at javelin.ProxySourceFile.codeGen(ProxySourceFile.java:222) 
    at javelin.SourceFile.codeGen(SourceFile.java:310) 
    at javelin.client.ClientUtilsImpl$CodeGenJob.run(ClientUtilsImpl.java:1105) 
    at javelin.client.Job.performJob(Job.java:81) 
    at javelin.client.ThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPool.java:215) 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mirror/declaration/ClassDeclaration 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) 
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source) 
    at javelin.mirror.Utilities.createMirrorType(Utilities.java:68) 
    at javelin.mirror.Utilities.createReferenceType(Utilities.java:85) 
    at javelin.ProxySourceFile$ProxyEnv.getTypeDeclaration(ProxySourceFile.java:806) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspLibrary.getClassInfo(JspLibrary.java:1259) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspActionChecker.check(JspActionChecker.java:163) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspCheckContext.check(JspCheckContext.java:78) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspAnalyzer.check(JspAnalyzer.java:59) 
    at javelin.ProxySourceFile._check(ProxySourceFile.java:152) 
    at javelin.SourceFile.masterCheck(SourceFile.java:777) 
    at javelin.SourceFile.check(SourceFile.java:297) 
    at javelin.SourceFile.check(SourceFile.java:318) 
    at javelin.ProxySourceFile.codeGen(ProxySourceFile.java:222) 
    at javelin.SourceFile.codeGen(SourceFile.java:310) 
    at javelin.client.ClientUtilsImpl$CodeGenJob.run(ClientUtilsImpl.java:1105) 
    at javelin.client.Job.performJob(Job.java:81) 
    at javelin.client.ThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPool.java:215) 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mirror/declaration/ClassDeclaration 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) 
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source) 
    at javelin.mirror.Utilities.createMirrorType(Utilities.java:68) 
    at javelin.mirror.Utilities.createReferenceType(Utilities.java:85) 
    at javelin.ProxySourceFile$ProxyEnv.getTypeDeclaration(ProxySourceFile.java:806) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspLibrary.getClassInfo(JspLibrary.java:1259) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspScriptTransform.getHandlerInfo(JspScriptTransform.java:1524) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspScriptTransform.signActionAll(JspScriptTransform.java:590) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspScriptTransform.transformPage(JspScriptTransform.java:188) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspScriptTransform.<init>(JspScriptTransform.java:154) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspCheckContext.check(JspCheckContext.java:89) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspAnalyzer.check(JspAnalyzer.java:59) 
    at javelin.ProxySourceFile._check(ProxySourceFile.java:152) 
    at javelin.SourceFile.masterCheck(SourceFile.java:777) 
    at javelin.SourceFile.check(SourceFile.java:297) 
    at javelin.SourceFile.check(SourceFile.java:318) 
    at javelin.ProxySourceFile.codeGen(ProxySourceFile.java:222) 
    at javelin.SourceFile.codeGen(SourceFile.java:310) 
    at javelin.client.ClientUtilsImpl$CodeGenJob.run(ClientUtilsImpl.java:1105) 
    at javelin.client.Job.performJob(Job.java:81) 
    at javelin.client.ThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPool.java:215) 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mirror/declaration/ClassDeclaration 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) 
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source) 
    at javelin.mirror.Utilities.createMirrorType(Utilities.java:68) 
    at javelin.mirror.Utilities.createReferenceType(Utilities.java:85) 
    at javelin.ProxySourceFile$ProxyEnv.getTypeDeclaration(ProxySourceFile.java:806) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspLibrary.getClassInfo(JspLibrary.java:1259) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspScriptTransform.getHandlerInfo(JspScriptTransform.java:1524) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspScriptTransform.signActionAll(JspScriptTransform.java:590) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspScriptTransform.transformPage(JspScriptTransform.java:188) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspScriptTransform.<init>(JspScriptTransform.java:154) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspCheckContext.check(JspCheckContext.java:89) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspAnalyzer.check(JspAnalyzer.java:59) 
    at javelin.ProxySourceFile._check(ProxySourceFile.java:152) 
    at javelin.SourceFile.masterCheck(SourceFile.java:777) 
    at javelin.SourceFile.check(SourceFile.java:297) 
    at javelin.SourceFile.check(SourceFile.java:318) 
    at javelin.ProxySourceFile.codeGen(ProxySourceFile.java:222) 
    at javelin.SourceFile.codeGen(SourceFile.java:310) 
    at javelin.client.ClientUtilsImpl$CodeGenJob.run(ClientUtilsImpl.java:1105) 
    at javelin.client.Job.performJob(Job.java:81) 
    at javelin.client.ThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPool.java:215) 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mirror/declaration/ClassDeclaration 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) 
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source) 
    at javelin.mirror.Utilities.createMirrorType(Utilities.java:68) 
    at javelin.mirror.Utilities.createReferenceType(Utilities.java:85) 
    at javelin.ProxySourceFile$ProxyEnv.getTypeDeclaration(ProxySourceFile.java:806) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspLibrary.getClassInfo(JspLibrary.java:1259) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspScriptTransform.getHandlerInfo(JspScriptTransform.java:1524) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspScriptTransform.transformAction(JspScriptTransform.java:1185) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspScriptTransform.transformAll(JspScriptTransform.java:746) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspScriptTransform.transformPage(JspScriptTransform.java:195) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspScriptTransform.<init>(JspScriptTransform.java:154) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspCheckContext.check(JspCheckContext.java:89) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspAnalyzer.check(JspAnalyzer.java:59) 
    at javelin.ProxySourceFile._check(ProxySourceFile.java:152) 
    at javelin.SourceFile.masterCheck(SourceFile.java:777) 
    at javelin.SourceFile.check(SourceFile.java:297) 
    at javelin.SourceFile.check(SourceFile.java:318) 
    at javelin.ProxySourceFile.codeGen(ProxySourceFile.java:222) 
    at javelin.SourceFile.codeGen(SourceFile.java:310) 
    at javelin.client.ClientUtilsImpl$CodeGenJob.run(ClientUtilsImpl.java:1105) 
    at javelin.client.Job.performJob(Job.java:81) 
    at javelin.client.ThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPool.java:215) 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mirror/declaration/ClassDeclaration 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) 
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source) 
    at javelin.mirror.Utilities.createMirrorType(Utilities.java:68) 
    at javelin.mirror.Utilities.createReferenceType(Utilities.java:85) 
    at javelin.ProxySourceFile$ProxyEnv.getTypeDeclaration(ProxySourceFile.java:806) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspLibrary.getClassInfo(JspLibrary.java:1259) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspScriptTransform.getHandlerInfo(JspScriptTransform.java:1524) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspScriptTransform.transformAction(JspScriptTransform.java:1185) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspScriptTransform.transformAll(JspScriptTransform.java:746) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspScriptTransform.transformPage(JspScriptTransform.java:195) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspScriptTransform.<init>(JspScriptTransform.java:154) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspCheckContext.check(JspCheckContext.java:89) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspAnalyzer.check(JspAnalyzer.java:59) 
    at javelin.ProxySourceFile._check(ProxySourceFile.java:152) 
    at javelin.SourceFile.masterCheck(SourceFile.java:777) 
    at javelin.SourceFile.check(SourceFile.java:297) 
    at javelin.SourceFile.check(SourceFile.java:318) 
    at javelin.ProxySourceFile.codeGen(ProxySourceFile.java:222) 
    at javelin.SourceFile.codeGen(SourceFile.java:310) 
    at javelin.client.ClientUtilsImpl$CodeGenJob.run(ClientUtilsImpl.java:1105) 
    at javelin.client.Job.performJob(Job.java:81) 
    at javelin.client.ThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPool.java:215) 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mirror/declaration/ClassDeclaration 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) 
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source) 
    at javelin.mirror.Utilities.createMirrorType(Utilities.java:68) 
    at javelin.mirror.Utilities.createReferenceType(Utilities.java:85) 
    at javelin.ProxySourceFile$ProxyEnv.getTypeDeclaration(ProxySourceFile.java:806) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspLibrary.getClassInfo(JspLibrary.java:1259) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspScriptTransform.getHandlerInfo(JspScriptTransform.java:1524) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspScriptTransform.transformAction(JspScriptTransform.java:1185) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspScriptTransform.transformRemainActions(JspScriptTransform.java:725) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspScriptTransform.transformPage(JspScriptTransform.java:217) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspScriptTransform.<init>(JspScriptTransform.java:154) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspCheckContext.check(JspCheckContext.java:89) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspAnalyzer.check(JspAnalyzer.java:59) 
    at javelin.ProxySourceFile._check(ProxySourceFile.java:152) 
    at javelin.SourceFile.masterCheck(SourceFile.java:777) 
    at javelin.SourceFile.check(SourceFile.java:297) 
    at javelin.SourceFile.check(SourceFile.java:318) 
    at javelin.ProxySourceFile.codeGen(ProxySourceFile.java:222) 
    at javelin.SourceFile.codeGen(SourceFile.java:310) 
    at javelin.client.ClientUtilsImpl$CodeGenJob.run(ClientUtilsImpl.java:1105) 
    at javelin.client.Job.performJob(Job.java:81) 
    at javelin.client.ThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPool.java:215) 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mirror/declaration/ClassDeclaration 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) 
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source) 
    at javelin.mirror.Utilities.createMirrorType(Utilities.java:68) 
    at javelin.mirror.Utilities.createReferenceType(Utilities.java:85) 
    at javelin.ProxySourceFile$ProxyEnv.getTypeDeclaration(ProxySourceFile.java:806) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspLibrary.getClassInfo(JspLibrary.java:1259) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspScriptTransform.getHandlerInfo(JspScriptTransform.java:1524) 
    at javelin.jsp.JspScriptTransform.transformAction(JspScriptTransform.java:1185) 
    at        <Console encountered the following error Exception during        RequestDispatcher.include().
 Throwable: weblogic.servlet.jsp.CompilationException: Failed to compile JSP      /layouts/tableBaseLayout_netui.jsp 
 tableBaseLayout_netui.jsp:1:1: The superclass specified could not be resolved. 
 <%@ page language="java" %> 
 ^-------------------------^ 
 tableBaseLayout_netui.jsp:16:14: The tag handler class was not found           "org.apache.beehive.netui.tags.template.IncludeSection".
         <beehive-template:includeSection name="configAreaIntroduction"/><br/> 
         ^-----------------------------^ 
tableBaseLayout_netui.jsp:16:14: The tag handler class was not found     "org.apache.beehive.netui.tags.template.IncludeSection".
        <beehive-template:includeSection name="configAreaIntroduction"/><br/> 
         ^-----------------------------^ 
tableBaseLayout_netui.jsp:22:14: The tag handler class was not found   "org.apache.beehive.netui.tags.template.IncludeSection".
        <beehive-template:includeSection name="table"/> 
         ^-----------------------------^ 
tableBaseLayout_netui.jsp:22:14: The tag handler class was not found "org.apache.beehive.netui.tags.template.IncludeSection".
        <beehive-template:includeSection name="table"/> 
         ^-----------------------------^ 
Stack Trace: 
weblogic.servlet.jsp.CompilationException: Failed to compile JSP /layouts/tableBaseLayout_netui.jsp 
 tableBaseLayout_netui.jsp:1:1: The superclass specified could not be resolved. 
 %@ page language="java" %> 
  ^-------------------------^ 
tableBaseLayout_netui.jsp:16:14: The tag handler class was not found "org.apache.beehive.netui.tags.template.IncludeSection".
```

Answer (score 0):

Best to look at the changelog:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/upgrade/compat.html

and

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/notes/new.html

If you're using EJB 3, it won't run on version 9.

WebLogic will allow you to be backwards compatible, but forward compatibility is not guaranteed.